# Webview Undefined while executing a testcase in appium

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, webview, appium

I am using APPIUM, When i'm executing, its showing webview_undefined. But it should show the webview_(webviewName). How can i solve this issue ?

Comment: can you please explain your scenario in detail.. what you tried to solve this issue

Comment: I was automating an hybrid app, while switching, it only shows name native context. WebView Context is shown as webview_undefined. So how can I get all the webview context names ?

Comment: Try using **getContextHandles()** to get all the context names

Comment: Set contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String contextName : contextNames) {
     System.out.println(contextName);
     if (contextName
       .contains("WEBVIEW")) {
      driver.context(contextName);
      webViewFound = true;
      System.out.println("switched to webview");

Comment: I'm already using this

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code and its working for me. Please try this one.

```
 Set <String> totalViews = appiumDriver.getContextHandles();
 int count = 0;
 for(String page: totalViews) 
 {
  appiumDriver.context((page) totalViews.toArray()[count]);
  count =count+1;
  if(page.contains("change Window Value"))
  {
    System.out.println("Inside "+changeWindow);
    break;
  }
```

**Note** : Replace the 'Change Window Value' with your window value, like `Webview`, `Native`.